# testing a variable against NULL as well as something else

Tags: r

I want to test variables for certain properties, however these variables are often `NULL`.

I tried:

```
x = NULL
if (!is.null(x) & names(x) == 'a') {
  return(0)
}
```

But this returns:

```
Error in if (!is.null(x) & names(x) == "a") { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Is there any way around this?

I don't want to write:

```
if (!is.null(x)) {
  if (names(x) == 'a') {
    return(0)
  }
}
```

As this will grow quickly with lots of `else`s.

I tried coming up with a function that tests if `NULL` as well as an arbitrary test, but I'm having some trouble with scopes (I think):

```
 is.null.test = function(x, test = NULL) {
  if (is.null(x)) {
    return(FALSE)
  } else if (is.null(test)){
    return(FALSE)
  } else {
    eval(parse(text = test))
  }
}

test = 'names(x) == "a"'
is.null.test(x = list(shape = 'a'), test = test)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely positive if this is what you're asking for, but here are a few options. If you're working with a list and you want the index in the list where both your conditions are met, you could try this:

```
my_list <- list(j = c(8:17), b = NULL, a = c(2,8,0), k = NULL)
which(!is.null(my_list) & names(my_list) %in% "a")
[1] 3
```

If you really want `return(0)` like in your example, you could try this:

```
ifelse(!is.null(my_list) & names(my_list) %in% "a", 0, NA)
[1] NA NA  0 NA
```

In both cases, notice that I use `names() %in%` rather than `names() ==`. For your example `==` works fine, but if you want to use multiple names, the `%in%` is a little nicer.

```
ifelse(!is.null(my_list) & names(my_list) %in% c("a", "b"), 0, NA)
[1] NA  0  0 NA
which(!is.null(my_list) & names(my_list) %in% c("a", "b"))
[1] 2 3
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, give me some more details and I'll edit my answer.